# Loop through list of lists in Python and sum up all index 1, then all index 2 etc

Tags: python, list

Been trying to figure out a way to sum up each and every index in a list of lists in Python. For example a list of list like this:

```
carbon_dioxide = ([" ", "1990", "1991", "1992"], ["factories", "100", "101", "102"], ["food industry", "50", "51", "52"], ["transports", "25", "26", "27"])
```

I want to exclude the first list and then sum up index 1 in list 2 ("100") with index 1 in list 3 ("50") and 4 ("25").

Then i want the iteration to continue and sum up index 2 in all the lists.

I do not want to import any modules, just pure code since I am a beginner trying to grasp the basics. I tried different solutions but no. For example this one, but it gave me the whole list of lists except from list[0]:

```
for i in range(1, len(carbon_dioxide)):
    print(carbon_dioxide[i])
```

Do you have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: That’s a good start. Do you have any ideas on how to add up numbers given to you one by one as they will be with the loop you have?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to add carbon dioxide levels for each year if I am not mistaken. A more digest-able output might be a dictionary where you have a year to (sum of carbon dioxide levels) mapping.

```
year_nums = zip(*(c[1:] for c in carbon_dioxide))  # gives us a year and all the CO2 levels

output = {yn[0]: sum(map(int, yn[1:])) for yn in year_nums}

print(output)
>> {'1990': 175, '1991': 178, '1992': 181}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that is what you're looking for, still:

```
carbon_dioxide = ([" ", "1990", "1991", "1992"], ["factories", "100", "101", "102"], ["food industry", "50", "51", "52"], ["transports", "25", "26", "27"])

for k in range(1,4):
    for i in range(1, len(carbon_dioxide)):
        for j in range(i+1,len(carbon_dioxide)):
            carbon_dioxide[i][k] = int(carbon_dioxide[i][k]) + int(carbon_dioxide[j][k])
    print(carbon_dioxide)
```

Output:

```
([' ', '1990', '1991', '1992'], ['factories', 175, '101', '102'], ['food industry', 75, '51', '52'], ['transports', '25', '26', '27'])
([' ', '1990', '1991', '1992'], ['factories', 175, 178, '102'], ['food industry', 75, 77, '52'], ['transports', '25', '26', '27'])
([' ', '1990', '1991', '1992'], ['factories', 175, 178, 181], ['food industry', 75, 77, 79], ['transports', '25', '26', '27'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to your start.

```
results = [0]*(len(carbon_dioxide[0])-1)     # Initialize array for results
                                             # with all zeros
for sublist in carbon_dioxide[1:]:           # skips 1st sublist in crbon_dioxide
    for index, v in enumerate(sublist[1:]):  # skips first item in each sublist 
                                             # i.e. skips "", "factories", etc.
        results[index] += int(v)             # Add to result at index 'index'
        
print(results)  # [175, 178, 181]
```

​

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I get it. So just to make sure I totally understand, I am looping through a sublist collecting the value of each index and then adding it to the results list at that specific index? And then when the loops jumps to the next sublist the values of each index in that sublist is added to the values that are already in the results list for that index? Sorry for my bad english and my complicated summary :)